# How to check which option was selected in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
      require_once("SQLSrvConnect.php");
      $producten = '';
      
      //Get the headings from the database
      try{
        #$data = $verbinding->query("SELECT product_category, product_id FROM Productcategory WHERE Parent = '$rubriek' ORDER BY product_category");
        $data = $verbinding->query("SELECT product_category, product_id, parent FROM Productcategory ORDER BY product_category");

        # haal alle gegevens in 1 keer uit de database
        $categories = $data->fetchAll();
        
        foreach($categories as $cat) {
          if ($cat["parent"] === "-1"){
            echo '<form action="product-list.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="categorien" value="'. $cat['product_category'] .'"></form>';
            echo $cat['product_id'];
            //echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="product-list.php?page=overzicht&category='.$cat["product_id"].'">'.$cat['product_category'].'</a>';
            
        }
      }
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
           echo $cat['product_id'];
        if(isset($_POST['categorien'])){
          
          $producten = $cat['product_id'];
        }
        // $producten = $cat['product_id'];
        // $parent = $cat['parent'];
      }
    }
      
      catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Kan rubrieken niet laden";
      }
      ?>
```

Hello everyone, I have a list of rubrics that I am loading in her by using a foreach loop to get them from my database. I do have one question here though, how can I check whether the rubric was selected with the If statement so that I will be able to save that rubrics id. I cannot seem to be able to fix it. I would appreciate if someone could help me out. And my $cat['product_id'] is always 107706 when I echo it.

Comment: Since all of that is outside of your loop, then $cat will only contain the very last value. You probably want to move that check inside of your loop.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I had at that point and it did indeed echo 1 which is de last result. But what I need is that the result is which option I clicked, I thought of removing the foreach loop since it only shows the last result but it is just too perfect for listing the rubriks from the database.

Comment: The one that was clicked will be in `$_POST['categorien']`. So you can test `if ($_POST['categorien'] == $cat['product_category'])`

Comment: That was actually it, Thank you sooo much!!! I had been searching for it so long, and I gotta say im still a beginner. But anyway have a nice day :).